# How to upload image to server in flutter

Tags: flutter, file-upload, multipartform-data

How does uploading image to server works in flutter! The **`ImagePicker`** return a path to directory,what url should be sent to server and what url should be used to show image on app if I want to upload a `png` format with autorization token in `form-data` with key `profile_image` and to show the similar Image.Below is one of the multiple I tried..

```
asyncFileUpload(File file) async {
var request = http.MultipartRequest(
    "POST",
    _getUri(
      '/profilepicture',
    ));
var token = getHeaders();
request.headers["authorization"] = token as String;
;

var pic = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("profile_image", file.path);
request.files.add(pic);
var response = await request.send();

var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
print(responseString);
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you really want to achieve, What's the question? coz the code seems okay

Comment: @Davis When we pick image from phone to upload it return its directory, is the directory should be uploaded on server? because server expects a png File. after successfully uploaded what would be the image path to show image on app.

Comment: Does the response return a url? If so could you please show a snippet of the response so that we can add the url in the `FutureBuilder()`

Comment: does not return anything, just uploading.

Comment: Is the image an avatar? Or how would you be able to get the url apart from the response. If it's an avatar the get the user details response which will have the url

Comment: My guess is the profile image url can also be found in the user details request or the login response

Comment: yes you are right but this upload function doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250511/discussion-between-digamber-negi-and-davis).

Answer (score 0):

What you are sending to the server is `.png` file and what is supposed to be shown to the user is the image in the server(url path) not the url path from phone. Therefore if the response returns that url all you need to do is get hold of it in the `NetworkImage('url')` or `Image.network('url')`

Note: It would be easy if you first show the picked image in your view then have a button that does the submit to the server. If successful replace the image picked url with the url from the server

```
asyncFileUpload(File file) async {
    try {
      var request = http.MultipartRequest(
          'POST',Uri.parse('url'));
      var token = getHeaders();
request.headers["authorization"] = token as String;
      request.headers.addAll({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      });
      //request.fields.addAll({
       // 'user_id': userId,
      //});
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('profile_image',file.path));
      var response =  await request.send();

      var serverResponse = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
      final responseData = json.decode(serverResponse.body);

      if(response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201){
        return responseData;
      }else{
        return responseData;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error occurred: $e");
      return Future.error(e);
    }
  }
```